# Как перенаправить вывод подключенного устройства по minicom в файл или переменную?

Tags: консоль

Работаю на маке с устройством что подключено по миникому. Как в риалтайме перенаправит вывод консоли миникома в файл?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для записи в файл

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -C cap.txt
```

В файле будет всё что ответит устройство, например:

```
atz
OK
```

Включить-выключить захват в файл можно интерактивно <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>